# How can I find the equivalent 'batch_size' used in Keras from this Pytorch code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, pytorch

I am using Pytorch code from [github](https://github.com/nshaud/DeepNetsForEO/blob/master/SegNet_PyTorch_v2.ipynb)

I am trying to port this over to Keras. 
In particular, Keras uses `model.fit` for training the Neural net and has a `batch_size` parameter. I am trying to set this but cannot determine it in the Pytorch script linked above.

In the script, there is a function called `sliding_window` in box 4 where there is a parameter called `step`. I am not sure if this is the equivalent setting of `batch_size`.

Also, I am looking into how to set the learning rate scheduler from the box 11 in the Pytorch code:

```
base_lr = 0.01
params_dict = dict(net.named_parameters())
params = []
for key, value in params_dict.items():
    if '_D' in key:
        # Decoder weights are trained at the nominal learning rate
        params += [{'params':[value],'lr': base_lr}]
    else:
        # Encoder weights are trained at lr / 2 (we have VGG-16 weights as initialization)
        params += [{'params':[value],'lr': base_lr / 2}]

optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=base_lr, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)
# We define the scheduler
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, [25, 35, 45], gamma=0.1)
```

I have always used the default learning rate from Keras. Any insight on how to go about converting this scheduler into Keras code  would also be appreciated.

Comment: If you go to your link and search for "batch" you will find BATCH_SIZE = 10

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro found it. Any insight into how I can adapt a similar learning rate scheduler into Keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below find an example on how to write a Learning Rate scheduler in Keras:

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras import backed as K

class LRSchedule(Callback):
    def __init__(self, schedule):
        super(LRSchedule, self).__init__()
        self.schedule = schedule

    def on_train_begin(self, logs = {}):
        self.epoch_counter = 0
        self.schedule_index = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs = {}):
        self.epoch_counter += 1

        if len(self.schedule)  > self.schedule_index + 1:
            next_epoch = self.schedule[self.schedule_index + 1]
            if self.epoch_counter == next_epoch:
                K.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, self.model.optimizer.lr / 2.0)
                self.schedule_index += 1
```

In your code, you will call the callback in this way:

```
lr_scheduler = LRSchedule([25, 35, 45])
model.fit_generator(..., callbacks = [lr_scheduler])
```

Notice that this scheduler, when an epoch is reached, sets the learning to a lower value dividing by 2.  Modifying it to more fancy schedule policies is trivial.